# Wordpress link different color custom menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm currently working on a Wordpress website with an custom jQuery menu. And everything is working fine except for one thing. I want to add a active class to an menu item that corosponds with the current page.

So basicly when the viewer is on the page "catering" I want the catering menu button the have an different style then the rest. But because it's wordpress I can't put in the html so I guess it has to be done with PHP but that's really not my thing.

So I was wondering if any of you could point me in the right direction. Here is the link to the website http://no-illusions.nl/projecten/kokaanhuis/wordpress/# no pages are currently working but when you hover over a button a brown layer appears, I want that layer to be static  (when it's down) on the current home page but can´t figure out the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_nav_menu (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu). It attaches a current-menu-item class, as well as a few other useful classes (current-menu-ancestor, etc) for styling.  Plus you'll also be able to easily edit the menu with the menu admin page.